# Will preorder skins be usable on all of my PSN accounts?

Tags: overwatch

Ok so I bought Overwatch on my primary PSN account and I was wondering if the skins will also be present on other accounts if I use them on the same PS4?

Comment: When you mention other accounts, do you mean other PSN accounts?

Comment: Yeah like I have the psn account I purchased it on set as primary so I'm wanting to know if the other accounts will have the skin(s) from it as well or if the skins will only be available on the account that I purchased it with and just to clear up any confusion all the accounts are on the same ps4

Comment: I edited the question to improve the wording a bit. This is a good question, I hope you can get a satisfactory answer!

Comment: If nobody has an answer by the time its outs I'll just check and I'll post it here in case anyone else wants to know but hasn't gotten the chance to check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked and yes you get all the skins on all the accounts I have overgrown bastion and noire widowmaker and all the others 
EDIT: also just to clarify you only get to share the pre order skins across the accounts the skins you get from loot boxes obviously do not carry across accounts